# Polylang: pll_e() & pll__() on functions.php, doesn't work

Tags: functions, plugin-polylang

I've on functions.php some functions that echoes blocks of HTML.
Problem comes with Polylang plugin, that uses custom functions pll_e() and pll__().

Those works right on index.php on every theme, but doesn't work right on functions.php, wich basically always returns me the default language strings, even having'em registred on admin side.

So those blocks printed on index.php using pll_ functions, work fine. But same blocks printed on functions.php, always come in English.

I've posted this on oficial plugin support forum. No answers yet.

Someone here have an idea of what it can be?

Thank you so much!

Comment: I used `pll__` in `functions.php` without any problem. Are you sure you provided the required translation using `pll_register_string` or via the dashboard?

Answer (score 3):

I have no experience with the Polylang plugin, but I think it's safe to assume that this is has to do with load order of the Polylang plugin and your theme's `functions.php`. When you call a function in the global scope (i.e. not from within another function) of `index.php` or any other template file, it will be executed at a late stage in the page loading process, after WordPress has been completely initialized and even after the server has begun sending the response to the client.

A function called from the global scope of the `functions.php` file, however, will be executed at a much earlier point. During a typical page load, essentially what happens is first WordPress will set itself up, then load the plugins and at last the theme. However, this process is not as linear as you might think, as some plugins might depend on functionality which might not be available until WordPress is completely initialized, the theme is loaded or the page server response has begun. WordPress solves this by using [hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Hook_to_WordPress), which allows a plugin or theme to execute code at certain stages during the load process.

To make a long answer <s>short</s> even longer, what you need to do is to make sure you don't call `pll_e()` or `pll__()` until you are certain the Polylang plugin is ready. This can be determined by looking at its source (or perhaps its documentation), but I guess hooking onto to `init` hook will suffice. Functions called in the global scope of `functions.php` will be executed before the `init` hook, but by adding an `init` hook you can make a function run at a later stage. Here's how:

```
function my_setup() {
    global $some_var;
    $some_var = pll__('A string in need of localization', 'localization_domain'); // This is assuming that this function behaves analogous to __() 

    pll_e("We'll just echo this, somewhere", 'localization_domain');
}
add_action('init', 'my_setup');
```

Comment: Nop... it doesn't work... :( Don't know what to do!

Comment: What have you tried? Using other hooks than `init`? Also, I hope you didn't simply copy/paste my code as there was an error in it. :)

Comment: I had a look at Polylang and `pll__($string)` is just a wrapper around `__($string, 'pll_string')` which is built into WordPress. However, the plugin adds filters to `override_load_textdomain`, `gettext` and `gettext_with_context`. It also loads its own textdomain on the hooks `wp`, `login_init`, `admin_init` so likely the functions would be available after any of those. Also, once setup is complete it fires the `pll_language_defined` which might also we worth looking into. In general my best tip is having a look at the Polylang source in order to get an understanding of how it works.